# Avoid redundant calls to Vue component when needing to return different data from one component

Tags: performance, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm starting my journey with Vue and have a problem with passing data around.

I pass json data array from Flask to Vue and need to process it (eg. get sum or average). I do processing in one Vue component and return an array of data. Now, in order to have some values in one place in html and some values in other, I did 3 extensions of the component. Each one has it's own `template: '<span>{{value1 (or 2 or 3)}}</span>'` attribute.

The problem is that I see **the main computing function is ran 3 times**, one for each component extension. How can I avoid it? I guess this question refers more to which Vue data handling method should I use rather than javascript.

Below is the code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="my-main-div">
    <p>sum: <sumvalue :table='{{datafromflask}}'></sumvalue></p>
    <ul>
        <li><p>first: <firstvalue :table='{{datafromflask}}'></firstvalue></p></li>
        <li><p>last: <lastvalue :table='{{datafromflask}}'></lastvalue></p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Vue component and app**

```javascript
var numbers = Vue.component('numbers', {
    // pass json data using props
    props: ['table'],

    data: function () { //gets executed 3 times

        // first value in the data
        var firstVal = this.table[0][1];

        // last value in the data
        var lastVal = this.table[this.table.length][1];

        // sum of the values
        var sumVal = 0;

        for (var i=0; i < this.table.length; i++) {
            sumVal += this.table[i][0]
        };

        return {
            sum: sumVal,
            first: firstVal,
            last: lastVal
        };
    }
})


var app = new Vue ({
    el: '.my-main-div',
    delimiters: ['[[',']]']
});
```

**Vue component extensions**

```javascript
var sumvalue = numbers.extend({
    template: '<span>{{sum}}</span>'
})
Vue.component('sumvalue', sumvalue)


var firstvalue = numbers.extend({
    template: '<span>{{first}}</span>'
})
Vue.component('firstvalue', firstvalue)


var lastvalue = numbers.extend({
    template: '<span>{{last}}</span>'
})
Vue.component('lastvalue', lastvalue)
```

Comment: Put the data function in the parent component, and pass the values down as props.

Answer (score 0):

You could make these computed properties instead. That way, the function for each individual property will only get called when that property is accessed:

```js
const numbers = Vue.component('numbers', {
  props: ['table'],
  computed: {
    first() {
      console.log('`first` computed');
      return this.table[0][1];
    },
    last() {
      console.log('`last` computed');
      return this.table[this.table.length - 1][1];
    },
    sum() {
      console.log('`sum` computed');
      return this.table.reduce((n, i) => n + i[1], 0);
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('sumvalue', numbers.extend({
  template: '<span>{{sum}}</span>'
}))

Vue.component('firstvalue', numbers.extend({
  template: '<span>{{first}}</span>'
}))

Vue.component('lastvalue', numbers.extend({
  template: '<span>{{last}}</span>'
}))

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      datafromflask: [ [null, 7], [null, 5], [null, 3], [null, 3], [null, 8], [null, 2] ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>sum: <sumvalue :table='datafromflask'></sumvalue></p>
  <ul>
    <li><p>first: <firstvalue :table='datafromflask'></firstvalue></p></li>
    <li><p>last: <lastvalue :table='datafromflask'></lastvalue></p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds interesting. I pasted simplified code of mine, but actually in my case I have a single for loop that handles: average, sum, total count, min and max. Having multiple `computed` functions would require to run for loop once for each variable instead of once. How would I fix that? Can I access one of many returned values from `computed` in my template?